# Query that converts a start time and an end time into hourly records

Tags: sql, sql-server, readonly

The table contains where each record is a unique event. Each record has a start time and an end time. Each event represents man/hours logged.

I want to create a query that duplicates each record one time for each hour of the day that it spans, and associates the duplicate record with the hour of the day it represents. I also want the primary key to be repeated with the duplicate records.

The start and end times are datetimes.

I only have read access, which limits me a lot.

For an example, what I have looks like:

```
pk   StartTime           EndTime

1     Start date 1am   End date 3am
```

What I want is:

```
pk   HourOfDay 

1     1 am
1     2 am
```

I want this for all records in the table in a single query result.

The intent is to determine the true busiest hour of the day and to determine days where demand for services were higher than staffing levels.

What I have tried  since Dale Burrell's answer which works excellently is joining the table variable in the recommended manner, but I am having a hard time with the conditional join.

What I have tried, is after creating the table variables as suggested in solution 1 below, I attempted the following conditional join and keep getting syntax errors:

```
select
  T.id
  ,H.[Hour]
from
  @TimeSheet as T
  inner join @Hour as H on 
    case
        when datepart(hour, StartTime) < datepart(hour, EndTime)
        then H.[Hour] >= datepart(hour, T.StartTime) 
             and H.hour < datepart(hour, T.EndTime)

        when datepart(hour, StartTime) > datepart(hour, EndTime)
        then H.[Hour] <= datepart(hour, T.StartTime) 
             and H.hour > datepart(hour, T.EndTime)

        else datepart(hour, StartTime) = H.[Hour]
     end
```

sample data for case 1, start hour > end hour

```
pk   start                   end
1    '2018-01-01 01:00:000'  '2018-01-01 02:00:00
```

sample data for case 2, start hour < end hour

```
pk   start                   end
1    '2018-01-01 22:00:000'  '2018-01-02 01:00:00
```

sample data for case 3, start hour = end hour

```
pk   start                   end
1    '2018-01-01 01:00:000'  '2018-01-01 01:30:00
```

Comment: Are all start and end times exactly on the hour? What is the datatype? Hopefully not actually a string containing text that needs to be parsed

Comment: For my purposes, it only matters which hours of the day if falls between. For instance if 15 minutes of time are between 1am and 2 am I would want a separate record of that.

Comment: It is varchar data type

Comment: It is a date time in varchar format I should say. With cast, it would convert to date time with no other changes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is usually best to enumerate what you have researched and tried. Questions that ask how to do something without
demonstrating an attempt often go unanswered. Please think of Stack Overflow as a code correction service, not a code writing service. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives something like what you are looking for. I've left the edge cases for you, especially the midnight case :)

```
declare @Hour table ([Hour] int)
declare @TimeSheet table (id int, StartTime time, EndTime time)

insert into @Hour ([Hour])
  select 0
  union all select 1
  union all select 2
  union all select 3
  union all select 4
  union all select 5
  union all select 6
  union all select 7
  union all select 8
  union all select 9
  union all select 10
  union all select 11

insert into @TimeSheet (id, StartTime, EndTime)
  select 1, '01:00', '03:00'

select T.id, H.[Hour]
from @TimeSheet T
inner join @Hour H on H.[Hour] >= datepart(hour, T.StartTime) and H.[Hour] < datepart(hour, T.EndTime)
```

Comment: I wish it would let me post pictures, but I am too new and don’t have enough reputation. So now how do I do this substituting my column names from the strings you included? I need the second select statement to be the existing column names from the existing table.

Comment: Just replace `@Timesheet` with your table name, and all the `T.` references with your column names. Alternatively post your table structure as part of your question in text form (images are discouraged for code as they can't be copied and pasted).

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I see what you’re doing now. I think this will work. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I just found a problem. I have 2.9 million records. This should multiply them by about 2 instead I have returned only 1.5 million records.

Comment: The problem is in the records where the hour is not between the start hour and end hour because time is a circle. There are two other cases to account for. When the start and end hour are equal, and when the start hour is greater than the end hour. I’ve never tried using a case statement in a join before, can that be done?

Comment: A case statement should do the job. Update your question with data which illustrates these edge cases.

Comment: I attempted the conditional join, but I appear to be doing something wrong. I included the join with case statement I wrote that keeps giving me a syntax error I have been unable to understand why. I compared it with some other conditional joins posted and can’t see the difference.

Comment: @MTHogan240 please also add some sample data and expected results for the edge cases you are trying to solve for.

Comment: @MTHogan240 a case statement can only resolve to a value not an expression.

Comment: your solution works perfectly. for cases where the start hour is less than the end hour. I need to join the two tables differently based on three cases. One, starthour < endhour. Two, starthour > endhour. Three starthour = endhour.

Comment: For case 1 I want to join to all records in '@hour that are between start hour and end hour. For case 2 I want to join to all records in '@hour that are not between start hour and end hour. For case 3 I want to join to records in '@hour where '@hour.[Hour] = start hour.

Comment: @MTHogan240 For the third time please provide some actual sample data and results to demonstrate what you are trying to describe. Words are just not as clear as the actual data, and having the actual data means I know when I've solved the problem. (This applies to all questions asked on SO).

Comment: You don't need a case statement, you just need to use `AND` and `OR` to obtain the login you want, maybe the following `ON (datepart(hour, StartTime) < datepart(hour, EndTime) AND H.[Hour] >= datepart(hour, T.StartTime) AND H.hour < datepart(hour, T.EndTime))
OR (datepart(hour, StartTime) > datepart(hour, EndTime) AND H.[Hour] <= datepart(hour, T.StartTime) AND H.hour > datepart(hour, T.EndTime)
OR datepart(hour, StartTime) = H.[Hour]`

Comment: I added what you asked for. I apologize, I am really having a difficult time learning this forum. Keys that I am accustomed to doing one thing are doing another and formatting is all done manually or with code. That is another thing I am not accustomed to so I am a little slow. I appreciate your patience. I have only been doing this for about four months. So when I say I am new I mean I never wrote a single line of code before this year.